# Flutter with android studio from snap

Tags: android, flutter, snapcraft

I am trying to install flutter and I get the flowing error when I type "flutter doctor -v":

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale en_IL)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /home/guy/flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (2 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/guy/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/69/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/69/android-studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Could it be that android from snap preventing flutter to recognize Android license status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to accept the required licenses. Do so by running

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

on the terminal and then press `y` to accept each of it.